# Solving a programming-contest using Python

Tags: python

I found this problem, which I thought would be interesting to solve but couldn't really come up with a correct solution-

> Inside a room, there is a monster with
>   N heads, and a human (with 1 head).
>   The human has two laser guns. The
>   first gun, A destroys C1 heads when
>   fired and the second gun,B destroys C2
>   heads when fired [The guns may destroy
>   both the monster's as well as human
>   heads, but the guns prioritize monster
>   heads over human ones].
>
> Also, if after the firing of the gun
>   the monster has a positive non-zero
>   number of heads left, the monster will
>   grow additional heads. The monster
>   grows G1 heads when gun A is used and
>   it grows G2 heads when gun B is used.
>
> The problem is to input N, C1, C2, G1
>   and G2, then find out what would be
>   the shortest combination of
>   gun-choice(A or B) the human must use
>   to kill the monster(the monster dies
>   when No. of heads=0).
>   [Note- this problem is from a programming contest that has already ended]

I tried approaching this problem using recursion but found myself clueless about how to actually come up with the solution. So, if you could give some hints how to approach the problem, that'd be great.

Comment: You want help with a contest?  Isn't that cheating?

Comment: Please clarify if the programming contest has already occurred, or is happening/will happen.

Comment: oh, the programming contest has already ended... in fact, it was a while back

Comment: @Henk,Don,Mat,Mike,S.Mark: It seems fairly clear what is being asked, as can be seen from the answers or propose an edit. If people were unclear what is being asked, they could perhaps request clarification (only a few words seemed necessary) or suggest an edit perhaps? Alternatively if people feel http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ is a more appropriate venue, they could perhaps state that before closing the question? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:  Dijkstra's is not the optimal solution :)

Given this sentence: "The guns may destroy both the monster's as well as human heads"
I take it if you can shoot 10 heads and the monster only has 5 heads, you can't kill it because that would kill you too. Is that correct?

In any case, any solution would be of the form:
ABABAABBABBB... (some string of A's and B's)

On the final hit you kill C1 or C2 heads. On every other hit you kill C1 - G1 or C2 - G2 heads.

If the final hit is from A, you have to destroy N-A heads with shots doing (C1-G1) or (C2-G2) damage.
If the final hit is from B, you have to destroy N-B heads with shots doing (C1-G1) or (C2-G2) damage.

Any K can be represented in the form:

```
X*i + Y*j = K
```

Of course, X and Y have to be coprime, etc.
K heads can be destroyed by i shots of damage X and j shots of damage Y.

You can find out the values of i and j with the extended greatest common divisor algorithm.

Solve for X = (C1-G1), Y = (C2-G2) and K = (N-A)
Also solve for X = (C1-G1), Y = (C2-G2) and K = (N-B)
The smallest answer is the correct one :)

That's it :)

Comment: I don't think the choice of algorithm cares if you kill yourself; that logic would just be wrapped into how you generate possible states to search through. Whenever you would kill yourself, you just don't search down that path.

Comment: How does this take into account avoiding killing yourself?

Comment: I think if you can kill yourself in the progress, the solution would be just "AAAA..." if X > Y else "BBBB..." (use the bigger gun!). You assume that X and Y are coprime, but I guess they don't have to be. So there can be many solutions and you're looking for the solution where `i+j` is minimal. The extra human head makes sure there is always a solution (if X and Y are not coprime it might be impossible otherwise).

Comment: Surely you can see that if X and Y aren't coprime, then either K = K1 * gcd(X,Y) or there simply isn't a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see you have found a solution in C++ already using Dijkstra's algorithm: http://hashsamrat.blogspot.com/2010/10/surviving-monster-programming-problem.html

However, you seem to be thinking about 'recursion' and other methods.

*The solution is separate than the implementation.* Thus what you really want to do would be to use the same algorithm (Dijkstra's, which is just breadth-first search carefully done so you visit the shortest paths first), but in python rather than C++.

You could just copy the C++ line-by-line, using python idioms to make the code cleaner and more elegant. But you'll still be using the same algorithm. (Alternatively, you could Google for the hundreds of ways people have implemented Dijkstra's in python. Or you could write it yourself; all you need is a priority queue (see wikipedia), and if time isn't an issue, you can write a poorly-performing priority queue in the form of a dictionary-of-lists.)

edit: Thinking about it, if by "shortest set of choices" you just mean "fewest gunshots", you don't really need Dijkstra's at all; it's just breadth-first-search (which is equivalent to Dijkstra's when all edges have weight 1).

In particular, the logic to generate a new node is as follows:

```
def howManyHeadsLeft(currentHeads, damage, regen):
    newHeads = heads - damage
    if {this results in blowing off our own head} and newHeads>0: #modify depending on assumptions
        # we killed ourselves without taking monster down with us
        return {} # the empty set of possible search nodes
    else:
        newHeads += regen
        # we could just say return {newHeads} here,
        # but that would be terribly slow to keep on searching the same
        # state over and over again, so we use a cache to avoid doing that
        # this is called dynamic programming
        if {we have never seen newHeads before}:
            return {newHeads}
        else
            return {}

def newSearchNodes(currentHeads):
    return howManyHeadsLeft(currentHeads, atypeDamage, atypeRegen) | howManyHeadsLeft(currentHeads, btypeDamage, btypeRegen)
```

The 'goal' condition for the search is having just enough damage to kill the hydra without killing yourself (modify as appropriate depending on assumptions):

```
heads==1+atypeDamage or heads==1+btypeDamage
```

Of course it is also possible that no solution exists (regen > damage for both types of guns), in which case this algorithm might run forever, but could probably be modified to terminate.

Comment: We blow off on our head is damage > heads. This means newHeads will be negative and you will never enter your first case. I think the implication of the problem is supposed to be that you simply cannot take the shot if its gonna kill you even if the monster would be killed as a result.

Comment: I was aware, and implicitly bringing that assumption to light. Thank you nevertheless. One can then just change the code a little: just remove the "and newHeads>0" part of the condition.